# How to copy video files from iPhone 6 onto computer?

Tags: iphone, file, file-sharing, file-transfer

If I plugged my old iPhone 4 into a computer, all the files would automatically come up. But when I plug my new iPhone 6 into a computer, nothing happens. Did they change something in the iPhone 6, and I have to perform additional steps to view the files?

Comment: Is your computer a Mac or PC?

Comment: @bjbk I have both a PC and a Mac, and I tried it on both, with the same result. I don't care which one I transfer the files to.

Answer (score 2):

## Mac Solution

You can use **Image Capture** to manage your videos and photos on your iPhone 6.

**With Image capture:** Choose AutoImporter from the “Connecting this [device] opens” pop-up menu to transfer images from a device to your computer whenever you connect it to your computer.

Click the icon that looks like a box with a down arrow enclosed on the lower left corner:

[image: Connected iPhone dialog box]

Select your preferred application from the list to change which application comes up when plugging in your iPhone 6:

[image: Select Application]

From [Apple Support:](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH17894?locale=en_US)

> ### Image Capture:
>
> #### Transfer images and other items from your device
>
> Transfer images, video clips, and MP3 sounds to your computer from
> many cameras and devices that contain a camera, such as your
> ***iPhone***. Once you transfer the items, you can delete them from the device.
>
> Connect your device to your computer, then turn the device on. If the
> device is locked with a passcode, enter it.
>
> - In Image Capture, select the device in the Devices list.
> - Use the buttons at the bottom of the Image Capture window to view the thumbnails as a list or as icons to change the size of the
>   thumbnails, or to rotate or delete images.
> - From the Import To pop-up menu, choose where to save the images or which app to use to open the image.
> - To import only some of the photos, select those photos, then click Import. To import all the photos, click Import All.
> - **Choose AutoImporter from the “Connecting this [device] opens” pop-up menu to transfer images from a device to your computer whenever
>   you connect it to your computer.**

Select “Delete after Import” to remove the items from the device after transferring them to your computer. You can also select and delete individual items on your device, then press the <kbd>delete</kbd> key on your keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Mac, you can simply use built-in iPhoto software to move videos to the computer.
If you use Windows, first plug your iPhone into the PC using the USB cable.

For Windows XP:

1. Navigate to Start -> All Programs -> Accessories -> Scanner and Camera Wizard.
2. When the Select Device window appears choose Apple iPhone and hit OK.
3. Click Next to use the wizard. If you'd rather copy photos manually using Windows Explorer then choose "advanced users only."

Windows Vista:

1. Windows will automatically recognize the iPhone and an AutoPlay window will appear.
2. Select "Import pictures." If you'd rather copy photos manually using Windows Explorer then choose "Open device to view files."

Sometimes Windows will not recognize the iPhone. When using XP you may receive the following error:

The computer cannot detect the scanner or camera.

1. To fix this problem disconnect all USB devices.
2. Right click "My Computer" and select the device manager.
3. If you see an Apple mobile device listed right click and uninstall the driver.
4. Reboot your computer.
5. Reattach the iPhone and now it should recognize the device as a camera.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how exactly to use the built-in iPhoto software on a Mac?

Comment: Now let me show you how to transfer  videos from iPhone to Mac using iPhoto:1. Connect your iPhone with your Mac via cable 2. Run iPhoto on your Mac and find your iPhone in the left panel under devices 3. Choose to import selected or all photos and videos into iPhoto library 4. Switch to the Last Import tab. Press Edit -> Select All and then press Edit -> Copy to copy all photos and videos you just imported from your iPhone 5. Go to Finder, press Edit -> Paste XX Items and paste the imported photos and videos to your Mac hard drive. Hope you can success!